# what's the proper way to add Spring Security filter only for specific URL?

Tags: filter, spring-security

I am trying to add custom `Filter` to only specific URL, however the filter get applied to every request, regardless of URL and method, **does anybody know the proper way to fix this using latest from Spring Security**, i.e. not using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, because it is going to be deprecated. It according with:

- [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).

There are many similar questions here, but they either do not work for me, or they use the "old" approach such as:

- [Bypass Spring Security Filter for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110812/bypass-spring-security-filter-for-url)

I have number of endpoints exposed that all follow the pattern: `/api/**` however I need to provide some authentication for a specific endpoint: `/api/some/url` and a particular method (`GET` in this case), **how do I do this properly?**

**NOTE**: the endpoint URLs are all under `/api/*` (should they be called nested?)

My security configuration looks like this:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private MyFilter myFilter;

    public SecurityConfig(MyFilter pif) {
        myFilter = pif;
    }

    /**
     * Handling AuthZ & AuthN for most APIs. No AuthZ & AuthN.
     */
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers((requests) ->
                        requests.antMatchers("/"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest()
                        .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

    /**
     * Handling AuthZ & AuthN for GET /api/some/url.
     */
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain keyApiSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers((requests) -> requests
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/some/url").and())
                .addFilterBefore(myFilter,
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you expose your `MyFilter` class as a bean?

Comment: @AndrewThomas yes, of course

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you expose some `GenericFilter` implementation as a bean in spring-boot, it automatically puts it in a common filter chain for **any request**, because it doesn't know if it's a security filter or not - *it could be a logging filter or anything else*.

So this filter bean will be executed **regardless of spring-security**.

Your `defaultSecurity` filter chain doesn't have this custom filter, so `MyFilter` will be executed after spring security filter chain due to the order.

At the same time, `keyApiSecurity` filter chain sets this custom filter before `BasicAuthenticationFilter`, so it will be executed there, and will not be executed the second time, because basic `doFilter()` implementation of `OncePerRequestFilter`s  method [checks whether the request was already filtered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.java#L109) by the filter.

So, if you want your filter to work only as a security filter, you **should not expose it as a bean**, and you should set it in a security filter chain like this:

```java
.addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

Also you should think about setting the lowest priority for a "default" security filter chain, because if it's selected first - other security filter chains will be totally ignored. So I think some specific filter security chains should have higher priority.

**EDIT:**

If you can't set your security filter with the `new` operator because you rely on bean injection in this `Filter` implementation, you can override `shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request)` method of `OncePerRequestFilter`, for example like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    private final RequestMatcher uriMatcher = 
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/some/url", HttpMethod.GET.name());
    // some bean injection...

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // filter logic here...
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestMatcher matcher = new NegatedRequestMatcher(uriMatcher);
        return matcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

Then it will filter only matched requests, and putting it into the security filter chain will set its order.

Comment: @gai-jin I've edited my answer, see an example how to make it work with a filter bean, if you rely on bean injection there

Comment: sure! the most in 18 hours I will update you.. (timezones and I have some mandatory things to do in the next couple of hours)

Comment: `/` is the root path, `/**` is a wildacard for any path starting with `/`.

Comment: @AndrewThomas the solution you proposed is working! Thanks a lot!